# clearInterval not working, even with global var declaration

Tags: javascript, html, video, onload, clearinterval

Here is a piece of code I've been working on to change a video source URL if the main video repository (smugmug.com) is unreachable (ala corporate firewall).  Problem is that I have to run a loop to wait for `SMimage.src = "http://smugmug.com/favicon.ico";` to load, and this code is not exiting the loop when `smugMugChecked = true`.  `clearInterval()` does not appear to be working, even though I declared `checkInterval` as a global variable.

```
<head>
<script>
    var checkInterval = null;
    // check if SmugMug is reachable (run once only)
    var isSmugMug = "1";
    var smugMugChecked = false;

    var SMimage = new Image();
    SMimage.onload = function () {
        window.isSmugMug = "1";
        smugMugChecked = true;
        // The user can access SmugMug
    };
    SMimage.onerror = function () {
        // The user can't access SmugMug
        window.isSmugMug = "0";
        smugMugChecked = true;
    };
    SMimage.src = "http://smugmug.com/favicon.ico";

    function changeImage(p1, p2, p3) {

        checkInterval = setInterval(function () {
            if (smugMugChecked == true) {
                clearInterval(checkInterval);
                if (window.isSmugMug == 0) {
                    //Hello();
                    var player = document.getElementById(p1);
                    var mp4Vid = document.getElementById(p2);

                    player.pause();

                    // Now simply set the 'src' attribute of the mp4Vid variable!!!!
                    // (...using the jQuery library in this case)

                    //$(mp4Vid).attr('src', p3);
                    document.getElementById(p2).src = p3;

                    player.load();
                    //player.play();
                }
            }
        }, 500);

    }

</script>



</head>

<body>

<video id='video9.1' onloadstart="changeImage('video9.1','source9.1', 'http://videos.ultrasoundoftheweek.com/photos/i-fDJHzts/0/960D/i-fDJHztsD.mp4')" width="792" height="470" controls> <source id='source9.1' src="http://www.ultrasoundoftheweek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/heterotopic.mp4"/>
<source id='else2' src="http://www.ultrasoundoftheweek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/heterotopic.webm"/>
</video>

</body>
```

Comment: why not just `break`? Also, does `window.clearInterval(checkInterval)` work?

Comment: `window.clearInterval(checkInterval)` doesn't help.  would `break` stop a loop called through checkInterval?

Comment: It should, yes. You would put something like `if(smugMugChecked) {/*do your other stuff, then*/ break;}`. You should put this into a Fiddle. What I would also do is make another function called `playLocally()` and replace what's inside your `if(window.isSmugMug==0)` with that

Comment: break definitely stops the loop, but my new function playLocally() doesn't change the source when window.isSmugmug==0.  http://jsfiddle.net/4Z8HK/4/

Comment: It looks like its working to me. Maybe you could elaborate more on what is still going wrong?